# Architecture for loading C# assemblies with custom typed parameters

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, assemblies

I have a C# application build with MVVM pattern and some amount of additional assemblies that could be loaded separately. (Spectrometric application and some spectrometer modules for different types of spectrometers.)

[image: Application architecture diagram]

Additional assemblies have a list of internal settings (temperature thresholds, sensor color filtrations, etc.) of internally defined types.

The application has an interface for choosing and loading additional assemblies (user can choose what type of spectrometer to work with now). A list of internal settings for selected spectrometer should be shown to the user after choosing and connecting a spectrometer.

How implement this architecture? Are there any standard solutions for such situations?

Comment: Check MEF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

Comment: Is it covers a question with handling types defined in loaded assembly?

Comment: Using a plugin framework in a UWP does not make much sense.  A rock-hard requirement is that all dependencies are included in the appx package.  Nothing can be added or removed later.  You might as well load them all.

Comment: The question is not about plugins, but mainly about architecture of classes, interfaces, etc.

Comment: Is it a case to use Autofac IoC instead of MEF for implementing the design.